# Importing fs in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fs, node.js-fs

I'm trying to import TinyDB in an expo project but I need help with fs, because expo doen't allow fs as it is a third-party file system.

I try using react-native-fs but I don´t kow how to use it. Can someone help me?

This is my Code:

```
var TinyDB = require('tinydb');
var db = new TinyDB('../UserData.json');
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall react-native-fs and use [expo-file-system](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/) instead

Comment: but how do I uninstall it?

Comment: And no, I want to use nodejs's file system

Comment: npm uninstall --save <package_name>

Comment: expo-file-system is Node's FS for expo. Take a look at the docs I linked

Comment: But then how do I use it?

Comment: TinyDB uses the FS like this: 
var fs = require('fs');

Comment: You can either patch TinyDB to use expo-fs (look up patch-package), or use another DB that has built-in Expo support.

Comment: Yes but now have this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74871228/expo-app-stuck-on-splash-screen-after-exporting-it-from-snack