# Expo app stuck on splash screen after exporting it from snack

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I wanted to create a calculator in a snack in expo, but then I tried to use it with an external code editor and It just stopped working. It was stuck on the splash screen and neither android nor web showed anything.

The proyect in snack works perfectly, but when I exported it, it didn't show anything.

My App.js is:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import DrawerNavigator from './components/DrawerNavigator'

export default function App(){
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <DrawerNavigator/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

My package.json is:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~47.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "tinydb": "*",
    "expo-constants": "~14.0.2",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "4.9.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.7.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "*",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "*",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.9",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```